# Simplify the generators using the relations so that each generator is equal to the identiy

Tags: group-theory

I have been given a group with generators:

$$G=\langle A,B \mid A^8=I, B^2=A^4, BAB=A^3\rangle$$

I need to simplify the generators using the relations so each generator is equal to the identity.

I have $A^8=I$ (as is given), $B^4=I$ from squaring $(B^2)^2=(A^4)^2$, then $BABA=A^4\Rightarrow(BABA)^2=I$

I am supposed to be able to simplify further and get $ B^2 = I$ and $A^4=I$ but I cannot see how.

I need to have my group presentation in such a way that I can generate the entire group using the Todd-Coxeter Algorithm.

Comment: This the generalized quaternion group of order $16$.

Comment: Note the proper use of \langle, \rangle, \mid, and \Rightarrow in my edit to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get $B^2 = I$ and $A^4 = I$.  Take the permutation group
$P = \langle a,b\rangle$, where
$$a = (1, 2, 6, 13, 12, 16, 9, 3)  (4, 10, 15, 8, 5, 11, 14, 7),$$
and
$$b = (1, 4, 12, 5)  (2, 7, 16, 8)  (3, 10, 13, 11)  (6, 14, 9, 15).$$
Then, by computation, we have $a^8 = 1$, $b^2 = a^4$ and $bab = a^3$,
so the map $A\mapsto a, B\mapsto b$ defines a homomorphism from $G$ onto $P$ in which the images of $A$ and $B$ have orders $8$ and $4$, respectively. So, for instance, the order of $A$ in $G$ must be a multiple of $8$. Likewise, $B$ must have order divisible by $4$.  (In fact, this is an isomorphism and $A$ and $B$ indeed have orders $8$ and $4$.)